# How do I remove the duplicated code for this code sample?

Tags: java

Given the following code:

```
public interface DTMFKeys {

    public String getKeyStr();

    public static enum Sign implements TahoeDTMFKeys {

        SIGN_1("*1"), SIGN_2("*2"), SING_3("*3"), SIGN_4("*4"), SIGN_5("*5"), SIGN_6(
                "*6"), SIGN_7("*7"), SIGN_8("*8"), SIGN_9("*9");

        private String keyStr;

        private Sign(String keyStr) {
            this.keyStr = keyStr;
        }

        @Override
        public String getKeyStr() {
            return keyStr;
        }
    }

    public static enum Pound implements TahoeDTMFKeys {

        POUND_1("1#"), POUND_2("2#"), POUND_3("3#"), POUND_4("4#"), POUND_5(
                "5#"), POUND_6("6#"), POUND_7("7#"), POUND_8("8#"), POUND_9(
                "9#");

        private String keyStr;

        private Pound(String keyStr) {
            this.keyStr = keyStr;
        }

        @Override
        public String getKeyStr() {
            return keyStr;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I remove the duplicated code:

```
private Sign(String keyStr){
    this.keyStr=keyStr;
}

@Override
public String getKeyStr() {
    return keyStr;
}
```

Comment: You can't, really, but it's not as if it was that much code anyway.

Comment: Can you make the base class an `abstract` class instead of an interface? Or Is that not allowed?

Comment: @KarthikT: Not if you're using an enum.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ah ok, too bad

Answer (score 1):

It's not much code, so I wouldn't really worry about refactoring it away. Java enums can't extend other classes. Avoiding duplication in code is really about large amounts of complicated logic being repeated, not getter/setter fields.

If you're really worried about the 'duplication', you could do away with enums altogether?

```
public static String getKeyString(int n, char sign) {
  if (n < 0 || n > 9) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  if (sign == '#') {
    return ""+n+sign;
  else if (sign == '*') {
    return ""+sign+n;
  else {
    throw new IllegalAgumentException()
  }
}
```

Also, SING_3 is spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

it is nor possible nor desirable to remove these. since enums can't inherit from abstract classes it is not possible. `keyStr` is a private concept both to Pound and Sign classes which both are indepented conceptually from each other.